# convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datetime, ado

I have calender in the page and I have to get selected date and insert it into data base table.

The error message is :

```
 Insert : Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime.
Insert Into Bills (ClientID,Credit,PhysicianRef,Billdate,BillImage,Status) Values (@bClientID,@bCredit,@bPhysicianRef,@bBilldate,@bBillImage,@bStatus)Insert : Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime.
bBilldate
```

Comment: often caused by locale, date format: dd/mm/yyyy <=> mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: @Interaoi see answer and use sqlparameter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to check the table in sql server what datatype has been defined for each fields.

and after that in your code use SqlParameter class.

for example

```
int ClientID = Convert.ToInt32(txtClientID.text);

 yourcommandobject.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@bClientID,ClientID));
```

same continue for other parameters too.

for datetime value you can do like this 
add using System.Globalization namespace to your namespace list.

```
using System.Globalization;

Datetime Billdate = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text.Trim()).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
yourcommandobject.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@bBilldate,Billdate));
```

and if in sql server your BillDate column is nvarchar/vatchar or any string type datatype, then you can do like this.

```
string tempdate = yourcalendertool.SelectedDate;// here you need to get the selected date
string Billdate = DateTime.Parse(tempdate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 yourcommandobject.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@bBilldate,Billdate));
```

Comment: I have the tool calender not text box

Comment: what's the problem ? just replace your calender tool instead of textbox. That's it. Your work done

Comment: selected date will insert like string and i have to convert it to string ?